Average number of cycles in a directed regular graph?
A directed random regular graph is a graph where all vertices have exactly $d_{\rm in}$ edges going in and $d_{\rm out}$ going out. If the graph is undirected, i.e. all vertices have degree $d$, then the average number of cycles of length $\ell$ is given by $(d-1)^\ell/2\ell$.
What is the average number of cycles for the directed case?
Note that it cannot be naively $(d_{\rm in}d_{\rm out}-1)^\ell/2\ell$ because for a cycle to form, all edges must be in the same direction.
Edit:
I know of two different way to define directed regular graphs:

A $d_{\rm in}d_{\rm out}$-regular graph on $n$ vertices is chosen uniformly from the set of all $d_{\rm in}d_{\rm out}$-regular graphs (i.e., graphs where every vertex has
in-degree exactly $d_{\rm in}$ and out-degree exactly $d_{\rm out}$) on $n$ vertices without multiple edges.

A more practical definition is to assign $d_{\rm in} + d_{\rm out}$ stubs to each vertex and connect random pairs of vertices until their in-degree and out-degree are satisfied. This model allows loops and multiple edges but for $n\gg1$ the graph will be locally tree-like.



What is a directed random regular graph? How are you using randomness to assign directions to edges of a $d$ regular graph? For instance, just randomly assigning $d_{in}$ out of the $d$ incident edges to be inward will not work as it may create conflicts.

If you create the directed random regular graph by taking an undirected random regular graph (however that is defined) and then assigning each edge a random direction, then shouldn't the average number of cycles of length $l$ in the directed case be the same as the average number of cycles of length $l$ in the indirected case, but divided by $2^{l-1}$? As for each choice of random indirected graph and each cycle in it, it has a probability of $2^{1-l}$ of being an oriented cycle. But I would have to see the formal definitions, e.g. I am not sure if your cycles are based at some fixed point

@SaúlRM, by assigning each edge a random direction you will lose the constraint that each vertex has exactly in-degree $d_{\rm in}$ and out-degree $d_{\rm out}$. Otherwise dividing my naive formula by $2^{l-1}$ would have been sufficient indeed.
